# Improving performance of trapezoidal rule implemented in C

Tags: c, numerical-integration

I am trying to improve the performance (speed) of my integration algorithm. It is implemented in C using the extended trapezoidal rule. An example, where the function to be integrated is `x * exp(-x)` from 0.1 to 1000, is:

```
    double x, integral = 0; // initialize
    int N = 10000;          // number of points to use
    double h = 0.1;         // step size
    int X = 1000;           // end of integration domain
    for (int k = 2; k < N; k++)
    {
        x = k * h;
        integral += x * exp(-x);
    }
    // deal with end points
    x = h;
    integral += 0.5 * x * exp(-x);
    x = X;
    integral += 0.5 * x * exp(-x);
    integral = h * integral;
```

Ideally, I would like to use more of the CPU by either having the code vectorized or parallelized. However, I cannot get the Microsoft compiler on Windows to do this automatically (I am compiling using `cl /O2 /fp:fast /Qpar`).

Any tips on improving performance is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am wondering how Matlab does this. If you use trapz on an array in Matlab then all cores are active.

Comment: The easy way would be to split the integral and compute the partial results in different threads. Be aware that starting a thread has some overhead and may not actually improve performances if the number of steps is small. The hard solution would be to use the GPU to massively improve performance, but the overhead is even bigger and it would only be beneficial for a very large number of steps. Multithreading : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-c/, GPU computing : https://ulhpc-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gpu/opencl/

Comment: I doubt that for just 10,000 points, using a multi-threaded or multi-process approach would speed this up much if at all. For functions that have SIMD equivalents, you could use SIMD via OpenMP or do it yourself with intrinsics. However, exp() is not available in SSE/AVX, so you're probably stuffed in this case. By the way, the integral of xe^(-x) is -(x+1)e^(-x) so in this case, you could just calculate the integral directly.

Comment: This particular function is just an example. I am wondering how, e.g. Matlab does this. When you run trapz over an array in Matlab all cores are active. I edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add `/Qpar-report:2` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/auto-parallelization-and-auto-vectorization) to make the compiler output the reason for unsuccessful parallelizations.

Compiling your code with `/O2 /Qpar /Qpar-report:2` leads to the message `loop not parallelized due to reason '1008'`. This reason code can be looked up at the [Vectorizer and parallelizer messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/vectorizer-and-parallelizer-messages) page. Code 1004 means that the loop was not parallelized because it contains scalar reduction.

You can still parallelize the computation of `x * exp(-x)` as follows:

```cpp
#include <math.h>

double integrate() {
    double x, integral = 0;  // initialize
    constexpr int N = 10000; // number of points to use
    double h = 0.1;          // step size
    int X = 1000;            // end of integration domain

    double f[N];

    #pragma loop(hint_parallel(0))
    for (int k = 2; k < N; k++) {
        double x = k * h;
        f[k] = x * exp(-x);
    }

    for (int k = 2; k < N; k++) {
        integral += f[k];
    }
    // deal with end points
    x = h;
    integral += 0.5 * x * exp(-x);
    x = X;
    integral += 0.5 * x * exp(-x);
    integral = h * integral;
    return integral;
}
```

`#pragma loop(hint_parallel(0))` is needed to force parallelization of the loop, otherwise it refuses to parallelize with the reason 1008 ("The compiler detected that this loop doesn't do enough work to justify auto-parallelization.").

Note that the code has to be compiled with C++ compiler, because msvc C compiler does not support `constexpr`.

Comment: For C, why not use `#define N 10000` instead of `constexpr int N = 10000;` ?